# How can I tell my app is about to become inactive/go to background state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multitasking, nsnotifications

I am assuming I need to implement:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(resignActive:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil];
```

but am not sure if this is the right notification to determine my app is about to leave active state.

Is this a good place to cancel network connections, along with app termination?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are cases where `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` is sent but the application does not enter the background, for example if a call is received but the user chooses not to answer it.

Use `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` to be notified when entering the background.  Be aware that this will sometimes be sent after `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` if the application is quickly opened again.